# How to change the Variation Label Name in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, variations, ootb

In SharePoint 2013 site settings for a site, I have created a variation label name as "en" as shown in the image below within a red box. Now I want to change it to "en-us".

[image: Image Link]

But according to my research that it is not possible to change it in any way through OOTB. Is it possible to change it through any other means? 
(For example, PowerShell or other means.)

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is no OOTB way to change the name of variation, Actually SharePoint trying to recreate the hierarchy when saving it.

As you see in the description it clearly mentioned that the label name cannot changed once it created.it make sense because it is part of the URL.

If you want to change then only way is recreate it.